# Android Studio Error Code 403: Gradle Sync Failed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Im starting to use Android Studio and from then, I encountered this nuisance of an error: Error:Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip

What I dont understand is that, why and what may be the cause of this error... Is there any work around on this? I have set this following lines in my gradle.properties file inside the Project (MyApplication3/gradle.properties)

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=192.168.140.19
systemProp.http.proxyPort=3128
systemProp.http.proxyUser=userid
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=localhost

systemProp.https.proxyHost=192.168.140.19
systemProp.https.proxyPort=3128
systemProp.https.proxyUser=userid
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=localhost
```

My System Admin said that there is no proxy user and password set so i dont know what to put on the proxyuser and proxypassword fields...

I hope there is someone that could help me :( im getting frustrated at this

Comment: Did you try to remove that lines for username and password or leave them empty?

Comment: I did that too, still gradle sync failed. I have check the work offline and still the same error.. this is frustrating..